# Function that approaches a unit square from a quarter unit circle

Tags: functions, circles, approximation

I would like to find an approximate, contiguous function $f(x, a)$ that approaches a unit square from a quarter unit circle according to an approaching factor $a$ :

$$
f(x,a)\approx\left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll}
1-\sqrt {1-x^2}\quad if\;a=0 \\
0\qquad\qquad\qquad if\;a=1\land x<1 \\ 
x=1\qquad\qquad if\;a=1\land x=1
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
$$\{x \, \epsilon \, \mathbb{R} : x \ge 0 \, \land x \le1\}$$

For example, in the image below $a=0.5$, meaning that $f(x)$ falls on the midpoint of the line between the unit circle and the unit square as $\theta$ sweeps from $0$ to $\pi \over 2$.

[Approaching a unit square from a unit circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMSkV.png)

$f(x)$ does not need to be defined at $a=0 \, \lor a=1$.

Comment: What is meant by symbol $\wedge$?

Comment: @LogicalGooGoo it means $and$. Something else should probably be used for set notation; what do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Fernández–Guasti squircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle#Fern%C3%A1ndez%E2%80%93Guasti_squircle) smoothly interpolates between a circle at $a=0$ and a square at $a=1$:
$$x^2+y^2-a^2x^2y^2=1$$
An explicit expression for $y$ is easily obtained:
$$y=\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1-a^2x^2}}$$
So $1-\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1-a^2x^2}}$ satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Amazing. This is exactly what I was looking for; thank you so much!